# Run mvn spring-boot:run from parent module?

Tags: spring-boot

I have a multi-module maven project like this:

my-parent
--my-domain
--my-service
--my-app   <<< this is a Spring Boot module

I want to run `mvn spring-boot:run` command directly from the parent module **without having to cd into the 'my-app' directory first**.

I figure this is related to configuration of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` but I can't seem to get it right.

I have tried the following:

1. Use `spring-boot-starter-parent` and otherwise default config with `spring-boot-maven-plugin` included in plugins section of my-app.
   Running `mvn spring-boot:run` from the parent results in:
   `Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project my-parent: Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property -> [Help 1] in the parent module`
2. Do NOT use `spring-boot-starter-parent`.
   Define `spring-boot-dependencies` in depManagement as described elewhere.
    Define `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in pluginManagement section of **my-parent** and include the plugin in plugins section of my-app module.
   Running mvn spring-boot:run from the parent results in same error as #1:
   Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:1.4.2.RELEASE:run (default-cli) on project my-parent: Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property -> [Help 1]
3. Do NOT use `spring-boot-starter-parent`.
   Define `spring-boot-dependencies` in depManagement as described elewhere.
    Define `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in plugins section of **my-app**.
   Running mvn spring-boot:run from the parent results in:
   `No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups`

In all cases described above, running `mvn spring-boot:run` from the my-app directory works fine.

I figure there should be a way to make this work.  In a traditional non-Boot Spring project it was fairly simple to configure `tomcat7` plugin such that i could run `mvn tomcat7:run-war` from the parent and the webapp sub-module would start as expected

Answer (score 56, accepted):

You can do it by  adding following In parent pom:

```xml
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skip>true</skip>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
```

And in your 
In my-app (Spring Boot module) pom:

```xml
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <fork>true</fork>
      <skip>false</skip>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>repackage</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

Now you can do execute in project root:

```
mvn -pl my-app -am spring-boot:run
```

Additional references:

- [spring-boot:run hot reload with multi module maven project · Issue #3436 · spring-projects/spring-boot · GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3436): in particular, [this comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3436#issuecomment-236213126).

Comment: @MohammedAtif [as you may find in docs](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.1.0/maven-embedder/cli.html) `-pl` allows to specify modules names to which you want to apply the command

Answer (score 3):

spring-boot maven plugin configuration options:

```
skip: skips the execution of sprint-boot:run  [default: false]

fork: Flag to indicate if the run processes should be forked [default: true]
```

see [spring-boot maven plugin parameters](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.2.2.RELEASE/maven-plugin/run-mojo.html)

maven options:

```
-pl, --projects: Comma-delimited list of specified reactor projects to build instead of all projects. A project can be specified by [groupId]:artifactId or by its relative path   

-am, --also-make: If project list is specified, also build projects required by the list
```

see [maven CLI options](https://maven.apache.org/ref/3.6.3/maven-embedder/cli.html)