# How to execute spring boot module from parent directory?

Tags: angular, spring-boot, maven, maven-module

I don't understand why this doesn't work; it seems like tutorials that use spring boot and angular as maven modules end up running things directly with java instead so this problem doesn't exist there... but I think this should still work right?

**TO RUN**
I am trying to run "mvnw spring-boot:run" from the parent POM (there is only one mvnw.cmd file and its in the parent folder).

**THE ERROR**
"No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups"

**Parent POM:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>project.site.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>artifactID</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>frontend</module>
        <module>backend</module>
    </modules>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**Spring Boot Module POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <groupId>project.site.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>backend</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>backend</name>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.3</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.2</version>

            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**Angular POM**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>project.site.org</groupId>
        <artifactId>videowall</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <groupId>project.site.org</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>frontend</name>

  <build>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
    </plugins>
  </build>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

`-pl` lets you run the Maven command against specific module from the project root. In this case:

```
./mvnw spring-boot:run -pl backend
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute `mvn` commands from where the `mvnw` script is stored, or you can provide the path for the same. Is there an `mvnw` directory at that level?

This might help:
[How to run Maven from another directory (without cd to project dir)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6478536/how-to-run-maven-from-another-directory-without-cd-to-project-dir)

Comment: no, only the parent directory has this folder

Comment: Please check the link I've attached if that helps.

Comment: thanks, I was missing the -f option. Also, I see I duplicated the question and this solution seems to work great, though I don't like having a spring plugin defined in the parent when its only applicable to the child and I don't fully get why this works or what it might break =). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092200/run-mvn-spring-bootrun-from-parent-module