# spring-boot:run in a Maven Multi-Module Project without mvn install

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I have a Maven multi-module project with the following structure (the code is posted below):

```
spring-altroot-reactor
  |
  +-- spring-altroot-reactor-lib
  |
  +-- spring-altroot-reactor-web
```

`spring-altroot-reactor-web` is a Spring web application depending on `spring-altroot-reactor-lib`. My goal is to run the Spring app without installing the artifacts into the local M2 repository.

After installing the modules with `mvn install` I can go to the `spring-altroot-reactor-web` directory and start the application via `mvn spring-boot:run`. This works as expected.

However, when I try to run `spring-altroot-reactor-web` without calling `mvn install`, I run into the following two errors:

- Calling `mvn spring-boot:run -pl :spring-altroot-reactor-web -am` in directory `spring-altroot-reactor` produces the following output:

  ```
   [ERROR] No plugin found for prefix 'spring-boot' in the current project and in the plugin groups [org.apache.maven.plugins, org.codehaus.mojo] available from the repositories [local ($HOME/.m2/repository), central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)] -> [Help 1]
  ```

  Enabling the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` in `spring-altroot-reactor` does not work either:

  ```
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.4.5:run (default-cli) on project spring-altroot-reactor: Unable to find a suitable main class, please add a 'mainClass' property -> [Help 1]
  ```

  Spring tries to execute the parent pom instead of the web project.
- Executing `mvn spring-boot:run` within the `spring-altroot-reactor-web` directory fails to find the dependency `spring-altroot-reactor-lib` because it is not installed:

  ```
   [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project spring-altroot-reactor-web: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.example.spring:spring-altroot-reactor-web:war:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.example.spring:spring-altroot-reactor-lib:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT in ... (my snapshot repo).
  ```

Is it possible at all to execute the Spring plugin and find the `spring-altroot-reactor-lib` dependency without installation to the local M2?

Other Maven plugins can do this, for example I have done it with the Jetty Maven plugin like so: `mvn jetty:run -pl :my-web-project -am` called from the root pom starts Jetty successfully.

*A small footnote: I do not inherit from the Spring Boot parent pom but add it as a dependency. I am not sure if this is relevant to the issue.*

The code follows.

spring-altroot-reactor/pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <groupId>com.example.spring</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-altroot-reactor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        
        <spring.boot.version>2.4.3</spring.boot.version>
        
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
        
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>spring-altroot-reactor-lib</module>
        <module>spring-altroot-reactor-web</module>
    </modules>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
            
                <plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.3.1</version>
                </plugin>
            
                <!--
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
                
                -->

            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

</project>
```

spring-altroot-reactor/spring-altroot-reactor-lib/pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-altroot-reactor</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>spring-altroot-reactor-lib</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
</project>
```

spring-altroot-reactor/spring-altroot-reactor-web/pom.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    
    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example.spring</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-altroot-reactor</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>spring-altroot-reactor-web</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-altroot-reactor-lib</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>

        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>

    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>

        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
                
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                        <property1>test</property1>
                        <property2>${my.value}</property2>
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
                
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
</project>
```

**EDIT: A solution was found thanks to [bekce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506813/bekce)'s comment below.**
This issue is a duplicate of [Run mvn spring-boot:run from parent module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092200/run-mvn-spring-bootrun-from-parent-module)
The proposed solution there works for me.

Comment: why don't you want to install it? (can't you re-consider!?:) "install without local repo" is called "package" in maven (so `mvn package` will build you everything without "installing" it...but this will help you only in an intelligent IDE/when you write your class paths by hand.

Comment: I am just asking if it is possible. I know that installing works, but I am wondering how does it work with the Maven Jetty plugin for example but not with Spring Boot? And I can use it without an IDE - it can be called from the command line.

Comment: @xerx593 If you change one module, and forget to re-install it, you wont see your change (happens to me all the time). Maven knows what has changed and in which order to build: Why do I have to tell it to Maven explicitly?

Comment: you have to: when you (only) `package`, maven will (using local repo): when you `install` ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41092200

Comment: bekce: Thank you! Indeed it IS a duplicate of that thread and the solution works for me! I will mark it as solved! Wow, thanks.